# How to draw with QPainter on a specific widget from a group of widgets in QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qpainter

This is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_QPushButton_calibration = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
    connect(m_QPushButton_calibration, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));

    QList<QCameraInfo> l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();

    m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder    = new QWidget;
    m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder->setStyleSheet ("background-color: black");

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder);

    if (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras.length() >= 2)
    {
        m_QCamera_required_camera = new QCamera (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras[1]);

        m_QCamera_required_camera->setViewfinder(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder);
        m_QCamera_required_camera->start ();
    }

    m_QWidget_central     = new QWidget;
    m_QGridLayout_central = new QGridLayout;

    m_QWidget_central->setLayout (m_QGridLayout_central);

    m_QGridLayout_central->addWidget (m_QPushButton_calibration, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    m_QGridLayout_central->addWidget (m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    this->setCentralWidget (m_QWidget_central);

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->show();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
    painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Qt");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete m_QPushButton_calibration;
    delete m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder;
    delete m_QCamera_required_camera;
    delete m_QGridLayout_central;
    delete m_QWidget_central;
}

void MainWindow::handleButton()
{
    qDebug() << "handleButton";
}
```

I actually wish to draw a line on `m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder` widget.

1. **How will that `QPaintEvent` function know where do I want it to draw line?**
2. **Can I use `QPaintEvent` as a member function in a class inherited from `QMainWindow`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to draw with QPainter on a specific widget from a group of widgets in QMainWindow?

You cannot draw on a widget from another widget. Each widget is responsible for drawing its own surface in the `paintEvent()` function.

---

> How will that QPaintEvent function know where do I want it to draw line?

First, note that `QPaintEvent` is a class, not a function.

Now you probably want to talk about the `paintEvent()` function.
The function "knows" where to draw because it is part of a widget and the widget has a geometry.

For instance if I want to create a `Rectangle` widget that draws a rectangle with a 5px margin, I would write something like:

```
void Rectangle::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    QRect rectangle(5, 5, width() - 5, height() - 5);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawRect(rectangle);
}
```

---

> Can I use QPaintEvent as a member function in a class inherited from QMainWindow?

You can reimplement the `paintEvent()` member function in any class that inherits `QWidget`. If you inherits from a class that already draws something you need to call your parent class function.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(event); // Let QMainWindow draw itself
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
    painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Qt");
}
```

However, please note that you are not likely willing to reimplement the `painteEvent()` of a MainWindow. What you generally want to do is to add a child widget to the MainWindow.

---

> I actually wish to draw a line on m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder widget.

Create a `ViewFinderHolder` class like so:

```
class ViewFinderHolder: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit ViewFinder(QWidget *parent = 0)
    ...
}

Reimplement the paintEvent() function:


class ViewFinderHolder: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit ViewFinderHolder(QWidget *parent = 0)
    ...
    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
}

void ViewFinderHolder::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QLineF line(10.0, 80.0, 90.0, 20.0);

    QPainter(this);
    painter.drawLine(line);
}
```

Finally in the MainWindow constructor replace:

```
m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder    = new QWidget;
```

by:

```
m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder    = new ViewFinder();
```

However, as `m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder` is a child of `m_QWidget_viewfinder_holder`, it will be drawn over it and may hide the drawing you did in `ViewFinderHolder::paintEvent()`.

---

On a side note, you can remove the delete statements in the destructor of MainWindow. Deleting an instance of MainWidow will delete its child widgets.

Comment: thankful for your detailed answer. BTW, regarding destructor - Isn't that what it should do? Destroy everything? Where should the destruction be done then?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl Generally you are right. But when using QObject classes, like QWidget, deleting an object will delete every child objects. This is handled within `~QObject()`. So deleting them yourself will not hurt, but it isn't necessary either. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html