# Draw inside widget on form QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new with QT so at the beginning I please for understanding.
My problem is that I would like to draw inside any widged contained on QT form. So for example I have overrided `paintEvent` method in this way:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(this);
    p.setBrush(Qt::red);
    p.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    p.end();
}
```

And everything is good, red rectangle appears on the form. Then I added for example `QWidget` somewhere on my form and I would like to draw inside this widget in this way:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(ui->widget);
    p.setBrush(Qt::red);
    p.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    p.end();
}
```

But nothing appears inside this widget. Is this possible to do ? Or maybe there are other methods to acheive my goal? The most important thing for me is that I would like to have any small place on my form which is designed only for drawing inside it.

Thank You very much for Your understanding and any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw with QPainter on a specific widget from a group of widgets in QMainWindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663880/how-to-draw-with-qpainter-on-a-specific-widget-from-a-group-of-widgets-in-qmainw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot draw in a widget from another widget. Each widget draws itself and only itself inside its own `paintEvent()` function.

For more details you should have a look at: [How to draw with QPainter on a specific widget from a group of widgets in QMainWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663880/how-to-draw-with-qpainter-on-a-specific-widget-from-a-group-of-widgets-in-qmainw/42668762#42668762)